# Showing the Cantor Function is Well-Defined on its Constant Intervals

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

**Setting:** Let $F:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ denote the Cantor Function.  In particular, we have that if $x \in [0,1]$ happens to be in an interval of form

$$
\left(\frac{3k+1}{3^m}, \frac{3k+2}{3^m} \right) \subseteq [0,1]
$$

with $k \in \{1,2,\ldots,3^{m-2}\}$ that then $F(x) = \frac{k+1}{2^m}$.  For example, if $x \in (1/3,2/3)$ then $F(x)$ is defined as

$$
F(x) = \frac{0+1}{2^1} = 1/2 = 0.1 \text{ (in base 2)}
$$

**Question:**  How do we know that $F$ is well-defined on these constant intervals?  For example, let let $x \in \left(\frac{3k+1}{3^m}, \frac{3k+2}{3^m} \right), \left(\frac{3j+1}{3^n}, \frac{3j+2}{3^n} \right)$.  Then how do we know that

$$F(x) = \frac{k+1}{2^m} = \frac{j+1}{2^n} = F(x)?$$

Comment: If $x$ is in both of those intervals, then $j=k$.

Comment: Please note that $k$ should be allowed to range from $0$ to $3^{m-1}-1$, and since some overlapping does occur, one has to take a minimal $m$ such that a suitable $k$ may be found (which effectively takes care of the definition).

Answer (score 0):

$F(x)$ is not well-defined as you have stated it.

For example take $x=\frac{1}{8}$.  Then $\frac18 \in \left(\frac{3\times 0  +1}{3^2}, \frac{3\times 0 +2}{3^2} \right), \left(\frac{3\times 3 +1}{3^4}, \frac{3\times 3 +2}{3^4} \right), \left(\frac{3\times 30 +1}{3^6}, \frac{3\times 30 +2}{3^6} \right),  \cdots $, which would give $F\left(\frac18\right) =\frac{1}{4}, \frac{4}{16}, \frac{31}{64}, \cdots$ and the third value is not equal to the second.

This is why the [Wikipedia definition of the Cantor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) looks at the *first* $1$ in the ternary expression of $x$.

In any case the range or image of your $F(x)$ is not $[0,1]$.  For example with $x=0.331$, the first interval it falls in is $\left(\frac{3\times 80  +1}{729}, \frac{3\times 80 +2}{729} \right)$ which would give $F(0.331)=1.265625$.   In fact the Cantor function applied to $0.331$ gives $0.484375$.